# How to fix this apt update keyring issue relating to gh?

Tags: apt, updates, 22.04, keyrings, github

I have this error associated with `gh` (github commandline).

```
$ sudo apt update
...                                                                                                            
Get:3 https://cli.github.com/packages stable InRelease [3,917 B]                                                                                                                     
Err:3 https://cli.github.com/packages stable InRelease                                                                                        
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 23F3D4EA75716059
...
Fetched 338 kB in 2s (154 kB/s)    
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://cli.github.com/packages stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 23F3D4EA75716059
W: Failed to fetch https://cli.github.com/packages/dists/stable/InRelease  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 23F3D4EA75716059
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

It's [installation commands](https://github.com/cli/cli/blob/trunk/docs/install_linux.md) are:

```
type -p curl >/dev/null || sudo apt install curl -y
curl -fsSL https://cli.github.com/packages/githubcli-archive-keyring.gpg | sudo dd of=/usr/share/keyrings/githubcli-archive-keyring.gpg \
&& sudo chmod go+r /usr/share/keyrings/githubcli-archive-keyring.gpg \
&& echo "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/githubcli-archive-keyring.gpg] https://cli.github.com/packages stable main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/github-cli.list > /dev/null \
&& sudo apt update \
&& sudo apt install gh -y
```

I think this means an issue relating to /usr/share/keyrings/githubcli-archive-keyring.gpg. I have uninstalled `gh`.

How do I remove this issue during `sudo apt update`?

Comment: If you don't want the GitHub repo, you can delete the file in which that repo is configured (`/etc/apt/sources.list.d/github-cli.list`, from the commands you have listed)

Comment: @muru Thank. I removed files `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/github-cli.list`, `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/github-cli.list.distUpgrade`, `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/github-cli.list.save`. Issues solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @muru comment, I removed files `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/github-cli.list`, `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/github-cli.list.distUpgrade`, `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/github-cli.list.save`. Issues solved.

**Sidenote:** After upgrading from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04, I also found many `focal` (i.e. Ubuntu 20.04) files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`. I removed these old files too.